# Backing up root device (mounted at /) of an AWS t2.micro instance running Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to back up the root device (mounted at /) of my t2.micro instance running Ubuntu. I think the instance is EBS-backed as it is a t2 instance. So I was going to take snapshots of my root device to back it up.

However, it is recommended that I detach the root device before I back it up. There are two problems with this:

1. I have to use `umount` to unmount it first, which may cause my instance to crash. What is a safe way to handle this?
2. I want to run these backups as a cron job on the instance itself, but if my instance's root device is unmounted, will the cron job even run?

A more general question is: what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be: use AWS Lambda and execute a Lambda function based on a schedule executing the following commands by the use of the AWS SDK:

1. Stop EC2 instance
2. Create EBS snapshot
3. Start EC2 instance

Comment: What if I have i/o happening on the disk when I stop the instance? Won't that cause problems?

Comment: And, is it possible to start back up a stopped instance?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to start a stopped instance.

Comment: During the shutdown the OS asks all processes to prepare for shutdown (e.g. flush caches to disk, ...). If your processes act like expected this shouldn't be a problem. And it is IMO the only possibility.

Comment: Just read this article automating EC2 backups using Lamda and python. If you can follow along possibly another option. Lamda has task scheduling so might be close to what you are looking for.

http://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups/

Answer (score 0):

First, I would confirm that your root device is in fact EBS backed.

Here are the basic steps to confirm:

> To determine the root device type of an instance using the console
>
> Open the Amazon EC2 console.
>
> In the navigation pane, click Instances, and select the instance.
>   Check the value of Root device type in the Description tab as follows:
>
> If the value is ebs, this is an Amazon EBS-backed instance.
>   If the value is instance store, this is an instance store-backed instance.

(Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html#display-instance-root-device-type)

AWS states as a best practice is to use snapshots or a backup tool.

> Regularly back up your instance using Amazon EBS snapshots or a backup
>   tool.

(Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-best-practices.html)

AWS states in the documentation that root EBS volumes should be shutdown before taking a snapshot.

> To create a snapshot for Amazon EBS volumes that serve as root
>   devices, you should stop the instance before taking the snapshot.

(Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html)

So depending on your RPO (Recovery Point Objective), as a general rule it is a good practice to separate your data from your root volume. Store data that you need to keep on a separate EBS volume and take snapshots on the second EBS volume. This way you never have to worry about the instance itself - if it bonks out just launch a new instance and attach your snapshot.

If you have a special case that prevents you from using EBS snapshots, try using a role for your instance(s) that have permissions to read/write data to S3 buckets using your cron job.

Comment: I just confirmed that my instance is EBS-backed. My problem is that I would like to take a snapshot of the root device so that I can restore a whole instance off of that snapshot (because I have config files that I want to back up). Separating just the data wouldn't solve that problem.

Comment: Maybe you should think about achieving a stateless server instead of backing up your root volume. That means don't store configuration and data only on your virtual server. Use a configuration management tool to provision your virtual server and outsource your data to a service like RDS, DynamoDB, S3, EBS, ...

Comment: What kind of config files do you want to backup? I don't mean to assume anything but as Andreas pointed out you really should think about a stateless or immutable instance - this is one of the benefits of moving to Cloud technology. I know this doesn't specifically answer your question but in the spirit of learning I recommend reading this AWS Well Architected Framework:

http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS_Well-Architected_Framework.pdf